# How can list comprehension be combined with traditional list definitions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a list in which list comprehension is used to create the first 16 entries but then manually add the rest of the entries without creating a nested list.

My code

```py
lst = [[x for x in range(16)], "a", "q", "l", "b", "s"]
```

I would like the output to be

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... 16, a, q, l, b, s]
```

However the output I am getting is

```
[[1, 2, 3... 16], a, q, l, b, s]
```

Comment: Even `[*range(16), "a", ...]` would be sufficient.

Comment: Note that lists support both `append()` and `extend()` methods that might be tangentially related to this task.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this differently

1. Complex logic

`lst = [i if i <= 16 else chr(96 + (i-16)) for i in range(1, 22)]`

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

2. Unpacking list elements

`lst = [ *[x for x in range(1, 16)], 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```